# Craft 3 CMS Update Error

Tags: craft3, plugins, updates

I try to update my craft3 cms system.

```
Ошибка: An error occurred

Вывод: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- The requested package oneup/contao-security-checker-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
Problem 2
- Installation request for craftcms/cms 3.0.22 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.22].
- craftcms/cms 3.0.22 requires enshrined/svg-sanitize ~0.9.0 -> satisfiable by enshrined/svg-sanitize[0.9.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
Problem 3
- craftcms/cms 3.0.22 requires enshrined/svg-sanitize ~0.9.0 -> satisfiable by enshrined/svg-sanitize[0.9.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- craftcms/redactor 2.1.6 requires craftcms/cms ^3.0.0-RC15 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.22].
- Installation request for craftcms/redactor 2.1.6 -> satisfiable by craftcms/redactor[2.1.6].

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see for more details.
- It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read for further common problems.
Running update with --no-dev does not mean require-dev is ignored, it just means the packages will not be installed. If dev requirements are blocking the update you have to resolve those problems.
```

Solution I've found is - to remove roave/security-advisories, but I still don't understand how I can do this. Same problems I have with plugin install.

Composer File

```
{
  "name": "craftcms/craft",
  "description": "Craft CMS",
  "keywords": [
    "craft",
    "cms",
    "craftcms",
    "project"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://craftcms.com/",
  "type": "project",
  "support": {
    "email": "support@craftcms.com",
    "issues": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues",
    "forum": "https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/",
    "source": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms",
    "docs": "https://craftcms.com/docs",
    "rss": "https://craftcms.com/changelog.rss"
  },
  "require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "3.0.18",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "v2.4.0",
    "craftcms/redactor": "2.1.5",    
    "dolphiq/craft3-forms": "1.1.0",
    "craftcms/contact-form": "2.2.2",
    "craftcms/guest-entries": "2.1.3",
    "nerds-and-company/schematic": "4.0.14",
    "symfony/yaml": "v3.3.6",    
    "illuminate/contracts": "v5.5.40",
    "illuminate/support": "v5.5.40",
    "nesbot/carbon": "1.32.0",
    "psr/container": "1.0.0",
    "psr/simple-cache": "1.0.1",
    "symfony/translation": "v3.3.6"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "@composer dump-autoload -o",
      "@php craft setup/welcome"
    ]
  }
}
```

thank for your answers

Comment: Is there a certain reason why you don't want to run the latest version of Craft? Because your composer json won't update it further than `3.0.18`. Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your "require" section with this in your composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "^3.0.18",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^v2.4.0",
    "craftcms/redactor": "^2.1.5",    
    "dolphiq/craft3-forms": "^1.1.0",
    "craftcms/contact-form": "^2.2.2",
    "craftcms/guest-entries": "^2.1.3",
    "nerds-and-company/schematic": "^4.0.14"
  },
```

Then, if you have Composer installed from the [command line](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx), run `composer update` from your project's root and let it finish.

Answer (score 0):

> Solution I've fount is - remove roave/security-advisories, but I still don't understand how I can do this.

To do that, open up your composer.json file, and remove this line:

```
"roave/security-advisories": "dev-master"
```

If that was the last line within your `"require"` object, make sure to delete the comma at the end of the line before it, too.

Comment: thx for your answer. But problem is I don't have this line in composer file, I've added this file to description

Comment: @AlexRyhluk can you send in a database backup and your composer.lock file over to support@craftcms.com?